# Custom Background-Image not showing up

Tags: wp-admin, css, custom-background, add-theme-support

I have added theme_support for my background-image and its showing up in the admin where I can set it and from there it looks as it should, but if i go to my website outside of the admin the background is completely white.

I can un-comment this section in my css to make it work

```
    body {
    font-family: Georgia, "Times New Roman", Times, serif;
    height:100%;
    /* background-image:url('../images/backgrounds/bg4.png'); */
    margin:0;   
}
```

but the whole idea is to be able to set it from the admin panel so the template can be used easily by others.

my support code looks like this:

```
    $args = array(
    'default-color' => '000000',
    'default-image' => get_template_directory_uri() . '/images/backgrounds/bg4.png',

);
add_theme_support( 'custom-background', $args );
```

also, if i inspect my site i can see the line:

```
body.custom-background { background-image: url("http://www.emcolsson.se/wp-content/themes/emcolsson/images/backgrounds/bg4.png"); background-position: left top; background-size: auto; background-repeat: repeat; background-attachment: scroll; }
```

which to me is saying that it works since I think its that line of code that is generated when an custom background is chosen from the admin panel, but at the same time it doesnt?

Comment: I can add that just using `add_theme_support( 'custom-background');`instead and then upload a file from the admin is what I want, but that ends up in the same way, i have just recently changed it to this code I posted first since I wanted to see if it made any difference

Comment: Since you already shared your domain, could you possibly provide a link where I can see the issue? Your current homepage does not have a bg image set from what I can see?

Comment: @Svartbaard Oops.. well, I deactivated my coming soon landing page for now so you can have a look. Now I have commented out the line in the css and in the wp-admin I have set the background-image.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It could be that you're missing the the `body_class()` in your theme:

```
<body <?php body_class(); ?>>
```

It should add the `.custom-background` as a *body class*:

```
<body class=" ... custom-background ... " >
```

Comment: That did indeed work! Thank you so much, I can now change in wp-admin and it makes the changes. Since im new to this I will soon encounter similar issues. Do you have any input or know wheres there documentation on what I do have to call to make everything work - like this one? Like for example if i would like to the same with custom header.

Comment: Glad to hear it worked. The best source is the code itself, The [Code Reference](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/) is helpful. It's also informative to look into the default themes to see how they are implementing things..Best of luck  @emcolsson